# Terminate Python script after one cycle

Tags: python, instagram, bots

I am using this Python Instagram bot:

```
https://github.com/LevPasha/instabot.py
```

What I am trying to do is following 50 people in 60 mins and then terminate the process. So I initialize the bot this way:

```
bot = InstaBot(
                login="your_login",
                password="your_password",
                follow_per_day=50,
              )
bot.time_in_day = 60*60
bot.new_auto_mod()
```

This runs for 60 mins and follows 50 users but then instead of terminating, it repeats the process and keep repeating itself.

How can I make it terminate after first loop (60 mins).

This is my example.pl:

```
from instabot import InstaBot

bot = InstaBot(login="myusername", password="mypassword",
               like_per_day=1,
               max_like_for_one_tag=1,
               follow_per_day=60,
               follow_time=5*60*60,
               unfollow_per_day=1,
               comments_per_day=1,
               tag_list=['cute', 'funny', 'lol'],
               log_mod=0)
bot.time_in_day = 60*60
bot.new_auto_mod()
```

And here is instabot.py

```
import requests
import random
import time
import datetime
import logging
import json
import atexit
import itertools

class InstaBot:
    """
    Instagram bot v 1.0
    like_per_day=1000 - How many likes set bot in one day.

    media_max_like=10 - Don't like media (photo or video) if it have more than
    media_max_like likes.

    media_min_like=0 - Don't like media (photo or video) if it have less than
    media_min_like likes.

    tag_list = ['cat', 'car', 'dog'] - Tag list to like.

    max_like_for_one_tag=5 - Like 1 to max_like_for_one_tag times by row.

    log_mod = 0 - Log mod: log_mod = 0 log to console, log_mod = 1 log to file,
    log_mod = 2 no log.

    https://github.com/LevPasha/instabot.py
    """

    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
    url_tag = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'
    url_likes = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/%s/like/'
    url_unlike = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/%s/unlike/'
    url_comment = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/comments/%s/add/'
    url_follow = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/%s/follow/'
    url_unfollow = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/%s/unfollow/'
    url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
    url_logout = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/'

    user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36")
    accept_language = 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'

    # If instagram ban you - query return 400 error.
    error_400 = 0
    # If you have 3 in row 400 error - look like you banned.
    error_400_to_ban = 3
    # If InstaBot think you have banned - going to sleep.
    ban_sleep_time = 2*60*60

    # All counter.
    like_counter = 0
    follow_counter = 0
    unfollow_counter = 0
    comments_counter = 0

    # List of user_id, that bot follow
    bot_follow_list = []

    # Log setting.
    log_file_path = '/var/www/python/log/'
    log_file = 0

    # Other.
    media_by_tag = 0
    login_status = False

    # For new_auto_mod
    next_iteration = {"Like": 0, "Follow": 0, "Unfollow": 0, "Comments": 0}

    def __init__(self, login, password,
                like_per_day=1000,
                media_max_like=10,
                media_min_like=0,
                follow_per_day=0,
                follow_time=5*60*60,
                unfollow_per_day=0,
                comments_per_day=0,
                tag_list=['cat', 'car', 'dog'],
                max_like_for_one_tag = 5,
                log_mod = 0):

        self.time_in_day = 24*60*60
        # Like
        self.like_per_day = like_per_day
        if self.like_per_day != 0:
            self.like_delay = self.time_in_day / self.like_per_day

        # Follow
        self.follow_time = follow_time
        self.follow_per_day = follow_per_day
        if self.follow_per_day != 0:
            self.follow_delay = self.time_in_day / self.follow_per_day

        # Unfollow
        self.unfollow_per_day = unfollow_per_day
        if self.unfollow_per_day != 0:
            self.unfollow_delay = self.time_in_day / self.unfollow_per_day

        # Comment
        self.comments_per_day = comments_per_day
        if self.comments_per_day != 0:
            self.comments_delay = self.time_in_day / self.comments_per_day

        # Don't like if media have more than n likes.
        self.media_max_like = media_max_like
        # Don't like if media have less than n likes.
        self.media_min_like = media_min_like
        # Auto mod seting:
        # Default list of tag.
        self.tag_list = tag_list
        # Get random tag, from tag_list, and like (1 to n) times.
        self.max_like_for_one_tag = max_like_for_one_tag
        # log_mod 0 to console, 1 to file
        self.log_mod = log_mod

        self.s = requests.Session()
        # convert login to lower
        self.user_login = login.lower()
        self.user_password = password

        self.media_by_tag = []

        now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        log_string = 'Insta Bot v1.0 start at %s:' %\
                     (now_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
        self.write_log(log_string)
        self.login()

        atexit.register(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup (self):
        # Unfollow all bot follow
        if len(self.bot_follow_list)>0:
            for f in self.bot_follow_list:
                log_string = "Try to unfollow: %s" % (f[0])
                self.write_log(log_string)
                self.unfollow(f[0])
                self.bot_follow_list.remove(f)

        # Logout
        if (self.login_status):
            self.logout()

    def login(self):
        log_string = 'Try to login by %s...' % (self.user_login)
        self.write_log(log_string)
        self.s.cookies.update ({'sessionid' : '', 'mid' : '', 'ig_pr' : '1',
                               'ig_vw' : '1920', 'csrftoken' : '',
                               's_network' : '', 'ds_user_id' : ''})
        self.login_post = {'username' : self.user_login,
                           'password' : self.user_password}
        self.s.headers.update ({'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
                               'Accept-Language' : self.accept_language,
                               'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
                               'Content-Length' : '0',
                               'Host' : 'www.instagram.com',
                               'Origin' : 'https://www.instagram.com',
                               'Referer' : 'https://www.instagram.com/',
                               'User-Agent' : self.user_agent,
                               'X-Instagram-AJAX' : '1',
                               'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'})
        r = self.s.get(self.url)
        self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken' : r.cookies['csrftoken']})
        time.sleep(5 * random.random())
        login = self.s.post(self.url_login, data=self.login_post,
                            allow_redirects=True)
        self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken' : login.cookies['csrftoken']})
        self.csrftoken = login.cookies['csrftoken']
        time.sleep(5 * random.random())

        if login.status_code == 200:
            r = self.s.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
            finder = r.text.find(self.user_login)
            if finder != -1:
                self.login_status = True
                log_string = 'Look like login by %s succes!' % (self.user_login)
                self.write_log(log_string)
            else:
                self.login_status = False
                self.write_log('Login error! Check your login data!')
        else:
            self.write_log('Login error! Connenction error!')

    def logout(self):
        now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        log_string = 'Logout: likes - %i, follow - %i, unfollow - %i, comments - %i.' %\
                     (self.like_counter, self.follow_counter,
                      self.unfollow_counter, self.comments_counter)
        self.write_log(log_string)

        try:
            logout_post = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : self.csrftoken}
            logout = self.s.post(self.url_logout, data=logout_post)
            self.write_log("Logout succes!")
            self.login_status = False
        except:
            self.write_log("Logout error!")

    def get_media_id_by_tag (self, tag):
        """ Get media ID set, by your hashtag """

        if (self.login_status):
            log_string = "Get media id by tag: %s" % (tag)
            self.write_log(log_string)
            if self.login_status == 1:
                url_tag = '%s%s%s' % (self.url_tag, tag, '/')
                try:
                    r = self.s.get(url_tag)
                    text = r.text

                    finder_text_start = ('<script type="text/javascript">'
                                         'window._sharedData = ')
                    finder_text_start_len = len(finder_text_start)-1
                    finder_text_end = ';</script>'

                    all_data_start = text.find(finder_text_start)
                    all_data_end = text.find(finder_text_end, all_data_start + 1)
                    json_str = text[(all_data_start + finder_text_start_len + 1) \
                                   : all_data_end]
                    all_data = json.loads(json_str)

                    self.media_by_tag = list(all_data['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]\
                                            ['tag']['media']['nodes'])
                except:
                    self.media_by_tag = []
                    self.write_log("Exept on get_media!")
                    time.sleep(60)
            else:
                return 0

    def like_all_exist_media (self, media_size=-1, delay=True):
        """ Like all media ID that have self.media_by_tag """

        if (self.login_status):
            if self.media_by_tag != 0:
                i=0
                for d in self.media_by_tag:
                    # Media count by this tag.
                    if media_size > 0 or media_size < 0:
                        media_size -= 1
                        l_c = self.media_by_tag[i]['likes']['count']
                        if ((l_c<=self.media_max_like and l_c>=self.media_min_like)
                            or (self.media_max_like==0 and l_c>=self.media_min_like)
                            or (self.media_min_like==0 and l_c<=self.media_max_like)
                            or (self.media_min_like==0 and self.media_max_like==0)):
                            log_string = "Try to like media: %s" %\
                                         (self.media_by_tag[i]['id'])
                            self.write_log(log_string)
                            like = self.like(self.media_by_tag[i]['id'])
                            # comment = self.comment(self.media_by_tag[i]['id'], 'Cool!')
                            # follow = self.follow(self.media_by_tag[i]["owner"]["id"])
                            if like != 0:
                                if like.status_code == 200:
                                    # Like, all ok!
                                    self.error_400 = 0
                                    self.like_counter += 1
                                    log_string = "Liked: %s. Like #%i." %\
                                                 (self.media_by_tag[i]['id'],
                                                  self.like_counter)
                                    self.write_log(log_string)
                                elif like.status_code == 400:
                                    log_string = "Not liked: %i" \
                                                  % (like.status_code)
                                    self.write_log(log_string)
                                    # Some error. If repeated - can be ban!
                                    if self.error_400 >= self.error_400_to_ban:
                                        # Look like you banned!
                                        time.sleep(self.ban_sleep_time)
                                    else:
                                        self.error_400 += 1
                                else:
                                    log_string = "Not liked: %i" \
                                                  % (like.status_code)
                                    self.write_log(log_string)
                                    # Some error.
                                i += 1
                                if delay:
                                    time.sleep(self.like_delay*0.9 +
                                           self.like_delay*0.2*random.random())
                                else:
                                    return True
                            # This media have to many likes!
            else:
                self.write_log("No media to like!")

    def like(self, media_id):
        """ Send http request to like media by ID """
        if (self.login_status):
            url_likes = self.url_likes % (media_id)
            try:
                like = self.s.post(url_likes)
                last_liked_media_id = media_id
            except:
                self.write_log("Exept on like!")
                like = 0
            return like

    def unlike(self, media_id):
        """ Send http request to unlike media by ID """
        if (self.login_status):
            url_unlike = self.url_unlike % (media_id)
            try:
                unlike = self.s.post(url_unlike)
            except:
                self.write_log("Exept on unlike!")
                unlike = 0
            return unlike

    def comment(self, media_id, comment_text):
        """ Send http request to comment """
        if (self.login_status):
            comment_post = {'comment_text' : comment_text}
            url_comment = self.url_comment % (media_id)
            try:
                comment = self.s.post(url_comment, data=comment_post)
                if comment.status_code == 200:
                    self.comments_counter += 1
                    log_string = 'Write: "%s". #%i.' % (comment_text, self.comments_counter)
                    self.write_log(log_string)
                return comment
            except:
                self.write_log("Exept on comment!")
        return False

    def follow(self, user_id):
        """ Send http request to follow """
        if (self.login_status):
            url_follow = self.url_follow % (user_id)
            try:
                follow = self.s.post(url_follow)
                if follow.status_code == 200:
                    self.follow_counter += 1
                    log_string = "Follow: %s #%i." % (user_id, self.follow_counter)
                    self.write_log(log_string)
                return follow
            except:
                self.write_log("Exept on follow!")
        return False

    def unfollow(self, user_id):
        """ Send http request to unfollow """
        if (self.login_status):
            url_unfollow = self.url_unfollow % (user_id)
            try:
                unfollow = self.s.post(url_unfollow)
                if unfollow.status_code == 200:
                    self.unfollow_counter += 1
                    log_string = "Unfollow: %s #%i." % (user_id, self.unfollow_counter)
                    self.write_log(log_string)
                return unfollow
            except:
                self.write_log("Exept on unfollow!")
        return False

    def auto_mod(self):
        """ Star loop, that get media ID by your tag list, and like it """
        if (self.login_status):
            while True:
                random.shuffle(self.tag_list)
                self.get_media_id_by_tag(random.choice(self.tag_list))
                self.like_all_exist_media(random.randint \
                                         (1, self.max_like_for_one_tag))

    def new_auto_mod(self, delay=60):
      import time
      now = time.time()
      while True:
        if time.time() - now > delay:
            break
            # ------------------- Get media_id -------------------
            if len(self.media_by_tag) == 0:
                self.get_media_id_by_tag(random.choice(self.tag_list))
                self.this_tag_like_count = 0
                self.max_tag_like_count = random.randint(1, self.max_like_for_one_tag)
            # ------------------- Like -------------------
            self.new_auto_mod_like()
            # ------------------- Follow -------------------
            self.new_auto_mod_follow()
            # ------------------- Unfollow -------------------
            self.new_auto_mod_unfollow()
            # ------------------- Comment -------------------
            self.new_auto_mod_comments()

            # Bot iteration in 1 sec
            time.sleep(3)
            # print("Tic!")

    def new_auto_mod_like(self):
        if time.time()>self.next_iteration["Like"] and self.like_per_day!=0 \
            and len(self.media_by_tag) > 0:
            # You have media_id to like:
            if self.like_all_exist_media(media_size=1, delay=False):
                # If like go to sleep:
                self.next_iteration["Like"] = time.time() +\
                                              self.add_time(self.like_delay)
                # Count this tag likes:
                self.this_tag_like_count += 1
                if self.this_tag_like_count >= self.max_tag_like_count:
                    self.media_by_tag = [0]
            # Del first media_id
            del self.media_by_tag[0]

    def new_auto_mod_follow(self):
        if time.time()>self.next_iteration["Follow"] and \
            self.follow_per_day!=0 and len(self.media_by_tag) > 0:

            log_string = "Try to follow: %s" % (self.media_by_tag[0]["owner"]["id"])
            self.write_log(log_string)

            if self.follow(self.media_by_tag[0]["owner"]["id"]) != False:
                self.bot_follow_list.append([self.media_by_tag[0]["owner"]["id"],
                                            time.time()])
                self.next_iteration["Follow"] = time.time() +\
                                                self.add_time(self.follow_delay)

    def new_auto_mod_unfollow(self):
        if time.time()>self.next_iteration["Unfollow"] and \
            self.unfollow_per_day!=0 and len(self.bot_follow_list) > 0:
            for f in self.bot_follow_list:
                if time.time() > (f[1] + self.follow_time):

                    log_string = "Try to unfollow: %s" % (f[0])
                    self.write_log(log_string)

                    if self.unfollow(f[0]) != False:
                        self.bot_follow_list.remove(f)
                        self.next_iteration["Unfollow"] = time.time() +\
                                self.add_time(self.unfollow_delay)

    def new_auto_mod_comments(self):
        if time.time()>self.next_iteration["Comments"] and self.comments_per_day!=0 \
            and len(self.media_by_tag) > 0:

            comment_text = self.generate_comment()
            log_string = "Try to comment: %s" % (self.media_by_tag[0]['id'])
            self.write_log(log_string)
            if self.comment(self.media_by_tag[0]['id'], comment_text) != False:
                self.next_iteration["Comments"] = time.time() +\
                                              self.add_time(self.comments_delay)

    def add_time(self, time):
        """ Make some random for next iteration"""
        return time*0.9 + time*0.2*random.random()

    def generate_comment(self):
        c_list = list(itertools.product(
                                    ["this", "the", "your", "i think", "think",
                                    "i'm sure this"],
                                    ["photo", "picture", "pic", "shot", "snapshot",
                                    "exposition"],
                                    ["is", "look", "", "feel", "really"],
                                    ["great", "super", "good one", "very good",
                                    "good", "so good", "wow", "WOW", "cool",
                                    "GREAT", "magnificent", "magical", "very cool",
                                    "stylish", "so stylish", "beautiful",
                                    "so beautiful", "so stylish", "so professional",
                                    "lovely", "so lovely", "very lovely",
                                    "glorious", "so glorious", "very glorious",
                                    "adorable", "excellent", "amazing"],
                                    [".", "..", "...", "!", "!!", "!!!"]))

        repl = [("  ", " "), (" .", "."), (" !", "!")]
        res = " ".join(random.choice(c_list))
        for s, r in repl:
            res = res.replace(s, r)
        return res.capitalize()

    def write_log(self, log_text):
        """ Write log by print() or logger """

        if self.log_mod == 0:
            try:
                print(log_text)
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print("Your text have unicode problem!")
        elif self.log_mod == 1:
            # Create log_file if not exist.
            if self.log_file == 0:
                self.log_file = 1
                now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                self.log_full_path = '%s%s_%s.log' % (self.log_file_path,
                                     self.user_login,
                                     now_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M"))
                formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s '
                            '- %(message)s')
                self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.user_login)
                self.hdrl = logging.FileHandler(self.log_full_path, mode='w')
                self.hdrl.setFormatter(formatter)
                self.logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
                self.logger.addHandler(self.hdrl)
            # Log to log file.
            try:
                self.logger.info(log_text)
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print("Your text have unicode problem!")
```

Comment: Did you expect that the `time_in_day` parameter would stop the process after 60 minutes? It doesn't. In `instabot.py`, line 367, I just see an infinite loop without stop condition. So you have to kill your bot manually.

Comment: I am running this bot with cron at specific day of time. Can we somhow stop/terminate it after say 65 mins? May be something I can do in cron if not possible with Python.

Comment: Yes, you can kill the process by cron 65 minutes after you've launched it. Or you can daemonize it and write a start/stop script. Or you can either patch the source and add a stop condition...

Comment: I am not expert so I don't know how to do any one of them. Can you show me any one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch method:

Update `new_auto_mod()` with something like:

```
def new_auto_mod(self, delay=60):
    import time
    now = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - now > delay:
             break
        # ------------------- Get media_id -------------------
        if len(self.media_by_tag) == 0:
             blabla
```

Comment: Hey, I just tested it and it did terminate script after 60 sec but it did not go through the following/like process.

Comment: Post your whole script and what you've changed in the instabot code

Comment: I edited my question and posted code for both of the files. I only changed username/password in `example.pl`

Comment: After the `break`, you indented the end of the function. Keep it just one level after the `while True`, as I did in my response.

Comment: What? You mean I should remove indent before other if statement.

Comment: Python is aware of indentation. Indentation defines blocks. If your `if` statements follow the break, they will never be executed. So keep the other `if` statements as they were before, that is too say, just 4 spaces more than the `while True` statement.

Comment: wow. I did not know Python work like that and a single space can ruin whole code. I just tested it and it's working fine. Thank you.